# Connecting to a remote SQL Server programatically in C++

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc

I have a C++ dll which has the code to connect to a remote SQL Server.
I use SQLDriverConnect API for this purpose. It works perfectly fine when i call it from a test app.

However when I deploy it as part of a wix installer, the conenction fails. On further debugging I identified that the exe that calls the dll function is running in System context and it tries to connect using the user NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON and gives the error [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON.

Is it possible to make the SQLDriverConnect pick the current workstation user rather than the "Anonymous" user in this case?

```
Sample code below.
 // Connect to data source
                retcode = SQLDriverConnect(
                    hdbc, 
                    0,
                    L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=TestMachine123;Trusted_connection=true;",
                    SQL_NTS,
                    OutConnStr,
                    255, 
                    &OutConnStrLen,
                    SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT );
```

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this executable is a Windows Service. You could try setting the service account in the Service Control Manager. Or you could create a login account for this check on the SQL Server. Give the account the minimum permissions necessary, then deploy the account details with the installer and have the executable load them up. You'll need to update your connection string with the username and password.